# Entity Framework Insert record without "addto" method

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4, crud

I'm new to EF. I have some code that successfully inserts a record in a table. However, it uses the autogenerated "addto..." method which I understand is depreciated. I've seen references to using the "add" method but am having trouble. Here is the code that works:

```
    Dim EntityContext As New DevEntities
    Dim log2 As New tblLog2

    log2.Error = "This is a test."
    log2.Date = System.DateTime.Now
    EntityContext.AddTotblLog2(log2)
    EntityContext.SaveChanges()
```

What is the "correct" way to insert this record (vb please)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [**ObjectSet<TEntity>.AddObject Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487277.aspx):

```
    ...
    EntityContext.tblLog2s.AddObject(log2)
    EntityContext.SaveChanges()
```

Basically *[ObjectSet.AddObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487277.aspx)* is a wrapper around the [*ObjectContext.AddObject method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx) so the above call is equivalent to :

```
EntityContext.AddObject("tblLog2s", log2)
```

Note: I assume that `tblLog2s` is the EntitySet name of`tblLog2` entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the classes that are generated by the designer (rather than your own templates), you would do:

```
Dim EntityContext As New DevEntities
Dim log2 As New tblLog2

log2.Error = "This is a test."
log2.Date = System.DateTime.Now
EntityContext.tblLog2.AddObject(log2)
EntityContext.SaveChanges()
```

The designer would also have created the following method for you, which you could use:

```
AddTotblLog2(ByRef item As tblLog2)
```

I'm guessing on the exact signature there, but you get the idea.